# Retrieve Gmail Labels with Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

According to [this thread](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26628&p=32620&hilit=gmail%20labels#p32620) (and various hints in the source code like variable names) Indy supports fetching gmail labels but not setting or removing them. However, as of yet, this functionality appears to be undocumented. Can anyone help me with filling in the details about how to retrieve Gmail labels with Imap?

Which function(s) should I call to retrieve the labels and have Indy parse out the results for me? Although I could certainly manually call SendCmd() to request the labels ('C2 UID FETCH 92 (X-GM-LABELS)') similar to how I'm manually setting/removing labels (which Indy doesn't yet do), parsing FETCH results is something that I know is already built into Indy, so I don't want to re-invent the wheel here to decode the FETCH results. For now, to keep things simple, presume I *just* want the labels and not other envelopes/headers/message parts.

There do appear to be quite a few functions that might (or might not) be relevant, but with so many to choose from, and so many of them only having auto-generated documentation, figuring out which one to try, and which property (or sub-property) or function to find the actual labels is a little daunting. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Indy supports fetching gmail labels but not setting or removing them.

Not quite.  `TIdIMAP4` supports searching for emails by Gmail label, but does not yet support retrieving Gmail labels for specific emails.

> However, as of yet, this functionality appears to be undocumented.

A lot of functionality added to Indy in the past several years is still undocumented.

> Can anyone help me with filling in the details about how to retrieve Gmail labels with Imap?

[Some GMail IMAP extensions added to TIdIMAP4](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20121128.aspx)

> The TIdIMAP4SearchKey enum has been updated with new items to support the X-GM-RAW, X-GM-MSGID, X-GM-THRID, and X-GM-LABELS extensions **in SEARCH commands issued by the SearchMailBox() and UIDSearchMailBox() methods**.
>
> The TIdIMAP4FetchDataItem enum has been updated with new items to support the X-GM-MSGID, X-GM-THRID, and X-GM-LABELS extensions in the FETCH command, however **no TIdIMAP methods currently use these new items yet**.
>
> **Support for the X-GM-LABELS extension in the STORE command has not been implemented yet**.

> Which function(s) should I call to retrieve the labels and have Indy parse out the results for me?

The only methods that support GMail labels at this time are `TIdIMAP4.SearchMailBox()` and `TIdIMAP4.UIDSearchMailBox()`.

> Although I could certainly manually call SendCmd() to request the labels ('C2 UID FETCH 92 (X-GM-LABELS)') similar to how I'm manually setting/removing labels (which Indy doesn't yet do), parsing FETCH results is something that I know is already built into Indy, so I don't want to re-invent the wheel here to decode the FETCH results.

Sorry, but you will have to.  Although `TIdIMAP4` does parse flags in `FETCH` responses, it discards any flag that is not supported by `TIdMessageFlagsSet` (Answered, Flagged, Deleted, Draft, Seen, Recent).  So while Gmail labels can be parsed automatically, `TIdIMAP4` has nowhere to save them yet.

> Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

At this time, you have to implement it manually.

Comment: so there's not a function I can call to partially parse the FETCH response for me leaving me the "unknown" tokens?

Comment: So far I have IMAP.SendCmd(ImapCmdNum(),'UID FETCH '+uid+' (X-GM-LABELS)',['OK','BAD','NO'], false); which is sending the right thing, and the server is sending back the responses according to the logs, but I'm having trouble finding the actual multi-line response that's more than just "OK" to even manually parse the response out of. IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text.Text seems to give an empty string, but I'm not sure I'm using the right property there.

Comment: Look at the implementation of `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveFlags()`. It calls `SendCmd()` followed by `ParseLastCmdResult()` to parse the returned flags. You will have to replicate the same logic, substituting `fdGmailLabels` where `fdFlags` is currently being used (minus the call to `ParseMessageFlagString()` that is parsing the flags string to a `TIdMessageFlagsSet`).

Comment: thank you, I'll have a look. PS. is improving the documentation for Indy an area where Indy would welcome contributions from outside developers since it's an open source project and all?

Comment: @JessicaBrown: Of course. On the other hand, the original files/tools used to create the existing docs are not available to us anymore, so I've had to experiment with tools to generate new doc files, but have not settled on anything yet.  So, you can contribute, but I'm not sure if/how it will get incorporated. But you can always submit a contribution and it'll get saved for now.

Comment: It looks like Rad Studio XE8 (which I don't have, but the documentation is online stating this) uses CHM based help instead of HxS. So one logical option might be to take the CHM version of the current documentation (10.5.8.3 on code.google.com?) and decompile/edit/recompile. Wouldn't automatically generate a bunch of placeholders for new functionality...but...could at least replace the @todos where Indy9 had useful documentation that didn't survive into the indy10 documentation (like TidImap4.Capability).

Comment: Anyway, comments on stack overflow is probably not the ideal (off topic?) place for discussing indy documentation requirements. Is there somewhere else that would be better to take this conversation? indydocs.feedback@gmail.com ?

Comment: You could start a discussion thread on [Indy's forum](http://forums2.atozed.com).