# How to get a parsable response from SendCmd in Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

If I use TIdImap4.SendCmd to manually send an unsupported command to Indy, I'm a little bit confused how I retrieve the full response to manually parse it.

I'm sending the following command to manually request the Gmail labels for a message since this is [not yet supported by Indy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420749/272208):

```
  IMAP.SendCmd(ImapCmdNum(),'UID FETCH '+uid+' (X-GM-LABELS)',['OK','BAD','NO'], false);
```

After calling this command, I checked my Indy Log file and it's successfully receiving an appropriate response from the server:

```
Sent 9/19/2015 11:10:40 AM: C5 UID FETCH 2385 (X-GM-LABELS)<EOL>
Recv 9/19/2015 11:10:40 AM: * 542 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (testlabel) UID 2385)<EOL>C5 OK Success<EOL>
```

But now I can't seem to get any part of that response other than 'OK' from Indy. I've tried the following in the debugger and none of them have the raw response or anything else I could possibly manually parse:

```
IMAP.LastCmdResult = ('OK', $2521E60, nil, $2521EC0)
IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text = ()
IMAP.LastCmdResult.Code = 'OK'
IMAP.LastCmdResult.NumericCode = 0
IMAP.LastCmdResult.FormattedReply = ()
```

From the SendCmd documentation:

> SendCmd is an overloaded function used to send the command specified
>   in AOut to the peer connection.
>
> SendCmd uses IOHandler to write the command in AOut to the peer
>   connection.
>
> AResponse indicates the response allowed for the command.
>
> **SendCmd calls GetResponse** to determine if the response from the peer
>   connection is allowed. If the response is not allowed, an exception is
>   raised during processing in GetResponse.
>
> When AResponse is contains -1, GetResponse is called with an empty
>   array to indicate that any response code is permitted for the command.
>   Otherwise, the value in AResponse is used to valid the response code.
>
> **Use LastCmdResult to access the numeric and text portions of the**
>   **response for the command.**

My understanding of this is that I should be using LastCmdResult to access various "portions of the response", but none of them have the raw response or any part of the response except "OK", so how do I get something parsable from the response to SendCmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are looking for is, in fact, in the `LastCmdResult.Text` property.  The debugger is not showing it to you, but that is where the label data is.

As I told you 2 months ago in comments to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420749/272208) that you linked to:

> Look at the implementation of `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveFlags()`. It calls `SendCmd()` followed by `ParseLastCmdResult()` to parse the returned flags. You will have to replicate the same logic, substituting `fdGmailLabels` where `fdFlags` is currently being used (minus the call to `ParseMessageFlagString()` that is parsing the flags string to a `TIdMessageFlagsSet`).

If you look at the implementation of `TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveFlags()` and then look at your code, you are not even calling `SendCmd()` correctly to begin with.  You are passing the wrong value to the `ATag` parameter (`unless ImapCmdNum()` is simply calling `TIdIMAP4.NewCmdCounter` - `TIdIMAP4` needs to generate the command counters so it can match them to the replies), and moe importantly you are passing the wrong values to the `AExpectedResponses` parameter.

Try this instead (I tested it and it works):

```
type
  TIdIMAP4Access = class(TIdIMAP4);
  TIdIMAPLineStructAccess = class(TIdIMAPLineStruct);

var
  uid: string;
  labels: string;
begin
  ...
  uid := ...;
  labels := '';
  IMAP.SendCmd('UID FETCH ' + uid + ' (X-GM-LABELS)', ['FETCH','UID']);
  if IMAP.LastCmdResult.Code = IMAP_OK then
  begin
    if IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text.Count > 0 then
    begin
      // The requested data is in IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text[0].

      // You can either parse it manually, or use the below
      // code to let TIdIMAP4 parse it for you...

      if TIdIMAP4Access(IMAP).ParseLastCmdResult(IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text[0], 'FETCH', ['X-GM-LABELS']) then begin
        labels := TIdIMAPLineStructAccess(TIdIMAP4Access(IMAP).FLineStruct).IMAPValue;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain all this. Once I changed the AExpectedResponses parameter as suggested, my LastCmdResult.Text was no longer empty, so I have something to move forward on parsing as previously mentioned.

Comment: That TIdIMAP4Access trick is pretty awesome too. If I had known there was such an easy way to access some of those non-public methods, I probably would have needed ImapCmdNum. ImapCmdNum basically replicated NewCmdCounter with an out of sequence C number...but now that I've fixed the expected responses correctly, using the overloaded version of SendCmd with automatic sequence numbering no longer results in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Indy has very few `private` members. Non-public members are intentionally `protected` so they can be accessed by descendants.  The "trick" takes advantage of a Delphi feature where a unit can access everything that is defined within the same unit. By deriving local classes from `TIdIMAP4` and `TIdIMAPLineStruct`, they gain access to the inherited `protected` methods, and then the unit gains access to their `protected` methods as well. The classes do not add additional data members or virtual methods of their own, so the vtable remains properly aligned, allowing the type-casts to work.

Comment: Using so-called *accessor classes* is a very common trick in Delphi code.  But it only works for `(strict) protected` members, which can be accessed through inheritance. `(strict) private` members cannot be accessed through inheritance, so this trick does not work for them.