# How to search email's SUBJECT or BODY with non-ASCII characters through TIdIMAP4

Tags: delphi, imap, indy, non-ascii-characters

`TIdIMAP4.UIDSearchMailBox()` works perfectly for ASCII characters, but for non-ASCII characters, such as in Persian/Farsi, the server doesn't return anything.

For example, when I search for emails that contain "foo" in the body, it works. But when I try to search for "سودابه", it does not work.

The IMAP command for my search is:

`C9 UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 UID 84:* BODY {N}\r\nsomething in Farsi that is encoded with UTF-8`

Where `84:*` is the range of email UIDs, `N` is the byte count of the UTF-8 encoded search text, and `\r\n` is a CRLF line break. The command will be submitted in two steps.

I'm pretty sure that there are some emails matching this search criteria.

I saw this issue on Gmail, Microsoft Exchange, and hMail servers.

Do you have any idea?

Here is abstract of my codes:

```
procedure TForm1.btn_GetMailsBySearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   :
   DoLog('Searching mail box started');
   if not id_IMAP.UIDSearchMailBox(FSearchInfoArray) then
   begin
     DoLog(SearchMailBox failed, True);
     Exit;
   end;   
   :
end;

procedure TForm1.DoLog(const ADesc: String; ADoLogLastResponse: Boolean);
var
  AStr: String;
begin
  :
  AStr := Format('[%s]: %s', [DateTimeToStr(Now), ADesc]);
  if ADoLogLastResponse then 
    AStr := AStr + Format('. Last response is "%s"', [GetLastResponseStr]);
  :  //saving AStr in file or memo 
end;

function TForm1.GetLastResponseStr: String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  with id_IMAP.LastCmdResult.Text do
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Result <> '' then Result := Result + #13#10;
      Result := Result + Strings[i];
    end;
end;
```

I didn't get any response via this approach, Did I go to wrong way?

Comment: Show your code. Could be something as simple as passing the wrong length (need to pass # of octets/bytes not characters since one character can take multiple octets after conversion to UTF8). Can't tell without the code.

Comment: @Brian the OP is not formatting the command manually. The `TIdIMAP4.UIDSearchMailBox()` method does. If the search criteria contains non-ASCII characters, UTF8 is used if the server supports UTF8, otherwise the caller has to specify a charset. Either way, when splitting up the command using IMAP literals, the charset-encoded byte count is used, not the character count.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved for hMail server by upgrading from version 3 to 4. but on other mail services is still remained.

Comment: In my case the difference between hMail server and others is using TLS while client and server is interacting with each other. for TLS I used `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` class for `IOHandler` of `TIdIMAP4` and `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` consequently. it seems a bug exists in Indy SSL library.

Answer (score -2):

As per [RFC3501 §6.4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4), you have to expect 3 types of responses:

- `OK` = server understands and supports your request; no search results matched, though
- `NO` = either the `CHARSET` or the search criteria is understood but not supported
- `BAD` = command or arguments are not supported; sloppy server implementations might return this for an unsupported `CHARSET`

So, are you actually looking at [what the server returns (i.e. thru `.GetResponse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675648/4299358)? Because "*it does not work*" might be missing that you have different expectations from what actually works as intended.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer

Comment: It's best to resist the temptation to post comments as answers.

Comment: This should be a comment: `What is the actual server response? Here's how you can get it`